# Add a space to UK Postcode in correct place Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, slice, indexof

I am trying to write a basic function that will allow me to add a space to UK postcodes where the spaces have been removed.

UK postcodes always have a space before the final digit of the postcode string.

Some examples with no spacing and with correct spacing:

```
CB30QB => CB3 0QB
N12NL => N1 2NL
OX144FB => OX14 4FB
```

To find the final digit in the string I am regex `/\d(?=\D*$)/g` and the Javascript I have in place currently is as follows:

```
// Set the Postcode
var postCode = "OX144FB";

// Find the index position of the final digit in the string (in this case '4')
var postcodeIndex = postCode.indexOf(postCode.match(/\d(?=\D*$)/g));

// Slice the final postcode at the index point, add a space and join back together.
var finalPostcode = [postCode.slice(0, postcodeIndex), ' ', postCode.slice(postcodeIndex)].join('');

return finalPostcode;
```

I am getting the following results when I change the set postcost:

```
CB30QB becomes CB3 0QB - Correct
N12NL becomes N1 2NL - Correct
CB249LQ becomes CB24 9LQ - Correct
OX144FB becomes OX1 44FB - Incorrect
OX145FB becomes OX14 5FB - Correct
```

It seems that the issue might be to do with having two digits of the same value as most other combinations seem to work.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: using the replace method is more simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I should use `string.replace`

```
string.replace(/^(.*)(\d)/, "$1 $2");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oD1fD2/1)

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with regex, you need to place space before 3 letters from the end

```js
document.write('CB30QB'.replace(/^(.*)(.{3})$/,'$1 $2')+'<br>');
document.write('N12NL'.replace(/^(.*)(.{3})$/,'$1 $2')+'<br>');
document.write('CB249LQ'.replace(/^(.*)(.{3})$/,'$1 $2')+'<br>');
document.write('OX144FB'.replace(/^(.*)(.{3})$/,'$1 $2'));
```

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else is answering, `.replace()` is easier. However, let me point what's wrong in the code.

The problem is you're using `postCode.indexOf()` to find the first occurence of what has been matched. In this case:

```
Text:     OX144FB
Match:        ^ match is correct: "4"

Text:     OX144FB
IndexOf:     ^ first occurence of "4"
```

---

To fix it, use the `.index` of the `match` object:

```javascript
// Find the index position of the final digit in the string (in this case '4')
var postcodeIndex = postCode.match(/\d(?=\D*$)/g).index;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var postCode = "OX144FB";

return postCode.replace(/^(.*)(\d)(.*)/, "$1 $2$3");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method is obviously the easiest way:

```
return postCode.replace(/(?=\d\D*$)/, ' ');
```

or using the greediness:

```
return postCode.replace(/^(.*)(?=\d)/, '$1 ');
```

Your previous code doesn't work because you are searching with `indexOf` the substring matched with the [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method (that is the last digit before the end). But if this digit is several times in the string, `indexOf` will return the position of the first occurrence.

As an aside, when you want to find the position of a match in a string, use the [`String.prototype.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) method that returns this position.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old problem, but whilst Avinash Raj's solution works, it only works if all your postcodes are without spaces. If you have a mix, and you want to regularize them to having a single space, you can use this regex:

```
string.replace(/(\S*)\s*(\d)/, "$1 $2");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jTf6Nj/1) - it even works with more than one space!